# assign type superclass to variable of type subclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, subclass

I'm just learning to program and trying to grab the concept of inheritance.

I have a superclass Book :

```
class Book {
   var author : String
}
```

and subclass :

```
class Comic : Book {
   var illustrator : String
}
```

I now have a function that returns a Book in another class

```
func someFunction() -> Book {
...
}
```

I thought this was possible :

```
var someComic : Comic
someComic = someFunction()
someComic.illustrator = "John"
```

as Comic is a subclass of Book, so I should be able to assign a book to a comic ? (comic inherits al vars of Book) but Swift wants me to cast :

```
someComic = someFunction() as! Comic
```

and then crashes at runtime...

**Below is an edit in reply to the Answer from Alexander**

Let's say that Book has 3 properties, and Comic has 2 extra properties (this resembles more the real situation than the example above).
The 2 properties I need in my Comic are fetched from external sources based on the value of properties in Book).

```
    let books = someFunction()
    var comics = [Comic]()
    for book in books {
       let comicProperty1 = getComicProperty(book.propertyA)
       let comicProperty2 = getOtherComicProperty(book.propertyB)
       let comic = Comic (book.propertyA, book.propertyB, book.propertyC,comicProperty1,comicProperty2)
       comics.append(comic)
}
```

Comment: It's the other way round – all `Comic`s are `Book`s, but not all `Book`s are `Comic`s.

Comment: mmmm strange. A Comic is bigger than a Book (2 properties vs 1). So if I put a Comic variable into a book Variable, the second property will be lost. If I put a Book into a Comic there is one unused variable ?

Comment: The second property won't be "lost" upon upcasting a `Comic` to a `Book` – the compiler just won't know anything about it, you'd have to downcast back to `Comic` in order to access it. But consider if you could assign a `Book` to a `Comic` – what value should the `illustrator` property have? `Book` doesn't have such a property – and Swift enforces that variables will never have garbage values (not unless using the "unsafe" family of APIs).

Answer (score 2):

> `Comic` is a subclass of `Book`, so I should be able to assign a `Book` to a `Comic` ?

No, it is the other way around: you can assign an object of type `Comic` to a variable of type `Book`, because every `Comic` is a `Book`. Assigning a `Book` to a `Comic` is prohibited, because not every `Book` is a `Comic`.

> Swift wants me to cast and then crashes at runtime.

That's because `someFunction` returns you a `Book` object that is *not* a `Comic`. Function signature lets it return any kind of `Book`, so the compiler cannot catch the error. Hence, you get an exception at run-time.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The Book/Comic was an example to make things easy here for my question, my real world objects have several properties. Now what is the best way to 'up-cast' a book into a Comic. I could create a new object Comic and in the init pass the values of all those properties of the book, but this seems a lot of work, isn't there a better way?

Comment: @Phil A book is not a comic. You can't up cast from book to comic, because book is below comic in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @Alexander, I know I can't up cast, that's why it's between quotes. I want to know if there is an alternative way (than creating a new object and filling the init with all the properties). I called that alternative 'up-cast' by lack of a better word. It seems a lot of work to create a new object with all those properties each time...

Comment: @Phil You're proposing a solution (your pseudo "upcasting"), running into a problem, and asking us for help on fixing the solution. We still have no idea what your actual problem is, so we can't help you.

Comment: @Phil `someFunction` returns a `Book`. Nothing you do will turn that book into a `Comic`. Downing casting to `Comic` will fail, because the concrete type of the return value is also `Book`, not `Comic`. Upcasting to `Comic` will fail because `Comic` is a subtype of `Book`, not the other way around. And that idea of `creating a new object with all those properties` will also not work, because `Book` lacks all the properties of a `Comic`.

Comment: @Phil What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? What is `someFunction`? Why does it return `Book`? Why are you using inheritance at all?

Comment: Book is a general class used in several projects (and I shouldn't touch it's implementation). It lacks some properties for this project, so I added them in a subclass Comic. In this project I always need those properties. In Book there is a static function findAllBooks, which returns an [Book]. I call that function, and want to make it an [Comic]. While making a Comic from each Book I would be filling in those missing properties. I could use the init from Comic but it would look like newComic = Comic(book.prop1, book.prop2,..., book.prop9, aNewProp, anotherProp)

Answer (score 0):

Given the information from your comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011361/3141234), I can now provide an answer. What you're looking for is not at all doable by casting.

### If you already have the supplemental data

Suppose you had some books, such as those you might obtain from `someFunction`:

```
let books = [book1, book2, book3]
```

And suppose you had some supplemental data you want to use to make your books into comics:

```
struct ComicSupplementalData {
    let illustrator: illustrator
    // Add other fields, if needed
}

let supplimentalData = [
    ComicSupplementalData(illustrator: "A"),
    ComicSupplementalData(illustrator: "B"),
    ComicSupplementalData(illustrator: "C")
]
```

You could make an extension on `Book` that promotes it to a `Comic`, given a `ComicSupplementalData`

```
extension Book {
    func promoteToComic(_ supplemental: ComicSupplementalData) -> Comic {
        return Comic(
            author: self. author,
            illustrator: supplemental. illustrator
            // Add other fields, if needed
        )
    }
}
```

Then you could convert your `Book`s to `Comic`s (note: This process has absolutely nothing to do with casting):

```
let comics = zip(books, supplimentalData).map{ $0.promoteToComic($1) }
```

### If you need to fetch the supplemental data

Just use map:

```
let books = someFunction()
let comics = books.map { book in
   return Comic(
       book.propertyA, book.propertyB, book.propertyC,
       getComicProperty(book.propertyA),
       getOtherComicProperty(book.propertyB)
   )
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, great solution. Very elegant way. Unfortunately I don't see how to implement it this way, because I don't have array of ComicSupplementalData. I have to fetch that data 1 by 1 (for each book) from external sources. I edited my question with the solution I came up with (not tested yet). It's far less elegant than yours but maybe you can pinpoint me on how to improve it.

Comment: @Phil Well just use `map` anyway, but with a different score for the properties. See my edit

Comment: @Phil Anytime you find yourself writing: `var Bs = [B](); for a in As { let b = transform(a); Bs.append(b) }` just stop and use `map` instead